# The derivative of det(X'A) when X is a non-square matrix

Tags: determinant

For a non-square matrix $X$ of size $n \times p$ ($n>p$) and another non-square matrix $A$ of size $p \times n$, what is the derivative of $\det(X^TA)$ w.r.t. $X$? i.e.,

$\frac{\partial\det(X^TA)}{\partial X}$

It'd be a matrix of size $n \times p$ while I got stuck in some intermediate steps of using chain rules.

Update: I think I got the solution. Thanks to AlexR and Bob.

Reference: The Matrix Cookbook; Section 2.1.2; Equation (45)

$\frac{\partial\det(AXB)}{\partial X} = \det(AXB){(X^{-1})}^T = \det(AXB){(X^T)}^{-1}$

This is, actually, a special case when A and B are non-singular matrices.

The more general form, according to matrix reference manual, is

(URL: http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/calculus.html#deriv_det)

$\frac{\partial\det(A^TXB)}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial\det(B^TX^TA)}{\partial X} = A\operatorname{adj}(A^TXB)^TB^T = A(\det(A^TXB)(A^TXB)^{-1})^TB^T = \det(A^TXB)A(B^TX^TA)^{-1}B^T$

When $B = B^T= I$

$\frac{\partial\det(X^TA)}{\partial X} = A\operatorname{adj}(A^TX)^T = A(\det(A^TX)(A^TX)^{-1})^T = \det(X^TA)A(X^TA)^{-1}$

Comment: Did you find $\partial_X \det X$ already? If not, you can compute $\partial_X \log \det X$ by using $\det X = \prod_{i=1}^p \lambda_i$ where $X\in\mathbb R^{p\times p}$. Then use the generalisation of the logarithmic derivative trick to obtain what you're looking for.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks for your suggestions first. However, $\det(X)$ is not meaningful given that $X$ is not a square matrix.

Comment: Note I write $\log \det : \mathbb R^{p\times p} \to \mathbb R$ wich _is_ meaningful.

Comment: Hi AlexR. Sorry I don't really get the idea behind $\log\det$. Can you name a reference? Cheers!

Comment: It's used in [Convex Optimisation](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf). The matrix cookbook is a better source if you don't need to prove it.

Comment: Please see my post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822397/notation-in-gradient-of-the-determinant

Comment: Please see my post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822397/notation-in-gradient-of-the-determinant

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\frac{\partial\det(XA)}{\partial X}=\det(XA)(X^T)^{-1} $ (see [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf), for example). Thus,

$\frac{\partial\det(X^TA)}{\partial X}=\det(XA)(X)^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi Bob. Thanks for your answer first. I have noticed that a similar form in The Matrix Cookbook but I don't think it's that straightforward as $X^{-1}$ suggests that X is a square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B=\operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)$$
Write the function and calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \det(X^TA) = \det(A^TX) = \det(M) \\
d\phi &= \phi M^{-T}:dM = \phi(A^TX)^{-T}:A^TdX = \phi A(X^TA)^{-1}:dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X} &= \phi A(X^TA)^{-1} \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

[$$\frac{\partial \mathrm{det}(X\cdot A)}{\partial X} = (A\cdot \mathrm{adj}(X\cdot A))^\top$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)