# Notation in gradient of the determinant

Tags: matrices, derivatives, notation, determinant, matrix-calculus

From page 631 of Dennis S. Bernstein's *Matrix Mathematics*, in equation (10.7.8):

> Let $A \in \mathbb{M}^{n \times m}$, and $B \in \mathbb{M}^{p \times n}$. For all $X \in \mathbb{M}^{m\times p}$, $$\frac{d}{dX}\mathrm{det}\, AXB =  B (AXB)^{\mathrm{A}} A.$$

---

I did not find the meaning of the notation $(AXB)^{\mathrm{A}}$ in the book. Can anyone help?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Here $X$ is not a square matrix. What do you mean $X^{-1}$.

Comment: The superscripted $A$ denotes the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)  (or classical adjoint) of the matrix.

Comment: @greg Thanks. I finally notice the subtle difference in the book about $A$ and adjugate $\mathrm{A}$.